# Getting the task input value in labeling job without using the Liquid Library

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm writing a custom Sagemaker Ground Truth job and I can't figure out how to get the `taskInput` values without using the Liquid form of `{{ task.input }}`.

I have searched everywhere, looked in localStorage, js variables, and the html itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `skip_autoescape` filter, otherwise Liquid will make your JSON HTML-safe (which makes it not JSON anymore).

**Template contents**

```html
<script>
    let x = {{ task.input.x | skip_autoescape }};
</script>
```

**Input object**

```json
{"x": ["foo", "bar"]}
```

**Rendered output**

```html
<script>
    let x = ["foo","bar"];
</script>
```

I use the command line to try these things out. Here's what the call looks like. `template.liquid` contains the template contents above.

```bash
aws sagemaker render-ui-template \
--ui-template "$(jq -csR '{"Content":.}' < template.liquid)" \
--task '{"Input":"{\"x\": [\"foo\",\"bar\"]}"}' \
--role-arn 'arn:aws:iam::00000000000:role/service-role/some-role' \
|jq -r .RenderedContent
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't get away from Liquid completely but you can minimize its use by transfering the entire {{task.input}} to the JS context. We initially tried to insert Liquid mustachios directly in a  tag in the custom UI, BUT it did not work (not in the context of sagemaker custom UI - even though Liquid's documentation indicates this should work and even gives examples of this).

Instead, we inserted the json form of task.input in a hidden div and instantied a js object by evaluating the content of that div

```
<div id="hidden_conversation">{{task.input | json }}</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  taskInput=eval($("#hidden_conversation").text());
</script>
```